# Adding a QJM or NFS for Hadoop Namenode Backup

Tags: hadoop

I am planning to deploy a hadoop cluster on cloud with 1 Master Node , 3 Datanodes and 1 Edge Node.
Before I do this I I want to keep in my mind the strategy to deploy so as to have a backup node for Namenode.
I have read that the secondary namenode helps the master node for faster boot up and updates the Editlogs and fsimage.
But it cant be used as a Namenode incase the masternode fails. I would be glad if i can get some clarification over this.
Also I want to know what is the best option regarding Namenode High Avalibility and how to deploy it. What are the steps to be take care of.
I am using IBM BigSights Enterprise Edition, it manages automatic Namdenode High avalibility but I want to manually configure a system to act as a cold stand by solution for the same.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about the Secondary NameNode, however, when running a Standby NameNode you should not have a Secondary NameNode. The reasoning is explained in the Hardware Resources [1] section on the HDFS HA Page(s).

As to whether you should use NFS vs QJM, I believe it depends on which is easier for you to manage. Of course, if you don't have NFS then QJM is the way to go.

[1] - http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html#Hardware_resources

Comment: I have the NFS, but want to know pros and cons of each way